# Apply inline style background image based on a ternary operator

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How can I apply:

```
<div v-bind:style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + item.packageAtGradeImage.url + ')' }"></div>
```

But only if item.packageAtGradeImage.url != null

?

Answer (score 0):

Just add computed property and bind it to `style`, make template more clean:

```
  computed: {
      styles() {
          if (!this.item.packageAtGradeImage.url) {
              return null;
          }
          return { 'background-image': 'url(' + this.item.packageAtGradeImage.url + ')' };
      }
  }
```

In template:

```
<div :style="styles"></div>
```